# Run script on a runat=server control

Tags: javascript, asp.net, runatserver

how can you run a script on a control that has a runat=server attribute?

Removing the runat=server makes the script run smoothly, but I wouldn't be able to access the control.

Here's the script. Any idea?

```
<input runat="server" type="text" id="txthSchedTime" readonly="true" class="asclock" style="width:100px; background-color:lightyellow" onclick="setTimePicker();" />
<script>
$("#txthSchedTime").AnyTime_picker(
{
format: "%h:%i %p", labelTitle: "Schedule Time",
labelHour: "Hour", labelMinute: "Minutes"
});
</script>
```

thanks

Comment: Use ClientID property of the asp.net control. If you are using master page then the server side control id will be changed at run time. Refer this https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.clientid%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: <script>$('<%=((HtmlInputText)fvVIPDtls.FindControl("txthSchedTime")).ClientID %>').AnyTime_picker... I did this but it' doesn't work

Comment: change it to $('<%=txthSchedTime.ClientID %>').AnyTime_picker{...}

Comment: The control is inside a FormView so I have to write it that way

Comment: can you put your complete designer code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can call the function from code behind like this :

yourForm.aspx.cs:

```
    protected void txthSchedTimeEvent(....)
    {
        Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "myScript", "myFunction();", true);
    }
```

yourForm.aspx

```
        <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
            <head id="Head1" runat="server">
                <title>My Page</title>
                <script type="text/javascript">
                    function myFunction(){
                    $("#txthSchedTime").AnyTime_picker(
                    {
                    format: "%h:%i %p", labelTitle: "Schedule Time",
                    labelHour: "Hour", labelMinute: "Minutes"
                    });
                    }
                </script>
            </head>
            <body>
                <form id="form2" runat="server">
                <table>
                    <tr> <td> 
                     <asp:TextBox ID="txthSchedTime" runat="server" 
                        style="width:100px; background-color:lightyellow">
                     </asp:TextBox>
                    </td> </tr>
                </table> 
                </form>
            </body>
        </html>
```

Comment: thou, the $("#txthSchedTime") doesn't work for me so I have to replace it by document.getEelement

Comment: ok but it should work for you if you have include the jquery.js file inside your <head> tag, good luck and if it works now please choose the best answer as accepted :) thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try using this for example :

```
 <input runat="server" type="text" id="txthSchedTime" readonly="true" class="asclock" style="width:100px; background-color:lightyellow" onclick="setTimePicker();" />
<script>
    $("#<%=txthSchedTime.ClientID %>").val('test');

</script>
```

Just tested it on my local machine. The input gets the value "test".

Comment: sadly, class selector still won't work if the control has a runat=server attribute

Answer (score -1):

After several attempts and trials it leads me to this.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function setTimePick() {
            var tp = document.getElementById('<%=((HtmlInputText)fvVIPDtls.FindControl("txthSchedTime")).ClientID%>');
            $(tp).AnyTime_picker(
            {
                format: "%h:%i %p", labelTitle: "Schedule Time",
                labelHour: "Hour", labelMinute: "Minutes"
            });
        }
    </script>
```

then i just call the function i made

```
<input runat="server" readonly="true" type="text" id="txthSchedTime" class="asclock" style="width:100px; background-color:lightyellow" onfocus="setTimePick();" />
```